# How to enable right click event and left click event in a YoutubePlayerView android

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data API to play youtube videos in my android app. I want to move the video forward by 10 seconds when the user clicks to the right of the youtubePlayerView (as in case of youtube app) and similarly, 10 seconds backward when the user click to the left of the youtubePlayerView. The basic code has been shown below -

```
 final YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.video_play_player_id);

    String videoUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoUrl");

    final String videoId = extractYTId(videoUrl);

    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The code you provided merely initializes the YouTube Player and doesn't actually show what you've tried to achieve the forward and rewind functionality by *click to the left of the youtubePlayerView* and vice versa.

Comment: You need to customize the container of the `YouTubePlayerView` and `override` `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`, `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` and detect a click, determine its position relative to the center of the View and perform the required (forward/rewind) operation.

Comment: Can you please show me some basic code how to do it? Only just hint I need.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml `layout` file you'll have something like

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ytPlayerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

Wrap it up with another custom `ViewGroup`, like so

```
<!--
    Make sure to prepend the complete package of the `CustomViewGroup`.
-->
<CustomViewGroup
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ytPlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
</CustomViewGroup>
```

Define your `CustomViewGroup`

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private boolean actionDownReceived = false;

    private final int DELTA_TOLERANCE = 70;
    private int actionDownX = -1;
    private int actionDownY = -1;

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context)
    {

    }


    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet)
    {

    }

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int defStyleAttr)
    {

    }

    //  Now write the appropriate methods to capture touch events.
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotoinEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                actionDownReceived = true;
                actionDownX = event.getRawX();
                actionDownY = event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Check if user moved his finger, there should also be a time check, i.e. if user pressed longer for a click. But I'll let you come up with it.
                if (Math.abs(event.getRawX() - actionDownX) >= DELTA_TOLERANCE) {
                    actionDownReceived = false;
                }
                else if (Math.abs(event.getRawY() - actionDownY) >= DELTA_TOLERANCE) {
                    actionDownReceived = false;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (actionDownReceived) {
                    if (isPressOnLeftSide(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY()) {
                        // Your logic for rewind.
                    }
                    else if (isPressOnRight(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY()) {
                        // Your logic for forward.
                    }
                    actionDownReceived = false;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEven.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                actionDownReceived = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        super.dispatchTouchEvent();
    }
}
```

<sup><sub>I haven't verified the code by running it so there might be syntactical and compiler errors, but as you asked for basic implementation, this should do.</sub></sup>